# Method size in an OOP language, for instance - in Java

Tags: java, object-oriented

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should be the maximum length of function](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/27798/what-should-be-the-maximum-length-of-function)

In Java (and I think in other OOP languages too) it is recommended to keep class methods as short as possible.

While I understand this recommendation I do not understand what is a "short-sized" method and "large-sized" method.

What is a particular criteria to determine that my java method is short enough?

Comment: [Your peer tells you after reviewing the code.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/141010/31260)

Comment: Could you please explain what do your comment and downvote mean? Thank you.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. Answering my question you tell me that my peer will tell me what is a short java method after reviewing my code. Right?

Comment: Right - comment points to what I consider most reasonable answer to questions like one you asked (_short enough_, _too long_ etc). As for downvote it is due to the fact that besides vague _it is recommended_ you did not refer to any other research you did prior to asking - "low effort question" as they say it here

Comment: Regarding "it is recommended" perhaps you're right. I supposed that most of users here have read classic OOP books. Regarding "Your peer tells you after reviewing the code" - it does not appear as a  polite answer. Ok then, have a nice day.

Comment: I didn't mean to be impolite. As for the answer I pointed to, you may be interested in a related [discussion at Programmers Meta](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3472/one-line-answers) - in particular I explained there why I think this answer is good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The cyclomatic complexity of a section of source code is the count of
>   the number of linearly independent paths through the source code.

Ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity

- I recommend that you keep that number under 10 in a single method. If it gets to 10, then it's time to re-factor.
- There are tools that can evaluate your code and give you a cyclomatic complexity number.
- You should strive to integrate these tools into your build pipeline.
- Don't literally chase a method size, but try to look at its complexity and responsibilities. If it has more than one responsibility, then it's probably a good idea to re-factor. If its cyclomatic complexity increases, then it's probably time to re-factor.
- I'm fairly certain there are other tools that give you similar feedback, but I didn't have a chance to look into this yet.